# Use Cloud Armor with Cloud Run and avoid bypass

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-load-balancer, google-cloud-armor

Quoting https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https-serverless#enabling

> While Google Cloud Armor can be configured for backend services with Cloud Run (fully managed), Cloud Functions, and App Engine backends, there are certain limitations associated with this capability, especially with Cloud Run (fully managed) and App Engine. Users who have access to the default URLs assigned to these services by Google Cloud can bypass the load balancer and go directly to the service URLs, circumventing any configured Google Cloud Armor security policies.

What would be the best way to avoid the bypass of Cloud Armor by an attacker targetting the Cloud Run URL (`*.run.app`)?

Normally I would make Cloud Run only invocable by a service account but Cloud Load Balancer can't use service accounts to call Cloud Run. An alternative is to configure Cloud Load Balancer to use a token in a header and configure the app running in Cloud Run to only accept calls with the correct header/token but I would prefer not to have to do that in the app.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should restrict the ingress of your service to "Internal and Load Balancing" to disable access from the default domain and only allow traffic to come from Cloud Armor:

```
gcloud beta run services update SERVICE --ingress internal-and-cloud-load-balancing
```

Comment: Thanks, it will be good to update https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https-serverless#enabling documentation specifying that you can now (although in Beta) configure Cloud Run ingress. I also note that this doesn't seem to be available in the google-beta Terraform provider yet.

Comment: Why isn't this option visible in the cloud console? When creating or editing a Cloud Run instance, I get only two options, Internal and All: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNMIg.png